# Is there anyway to get Telegram Group Admins without joining channel Telethon?

Tags: telethon

```py
async def get_group_admins(self):

        dialogs = await self.get_dialogs()
        for dialog in dialogs:
            if type(dialog.entity) == Channel:
                if dialog.entity.megagroup:
                    async for user in self.client.iter_participants(
                        dialog.name, filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins
                    ):
                        if not user.bot:
                       
                            participant = await self.client(
                                GetParticipantRequest(dialog.id, user.id)
                            )

                            if type(participant.participant) == ChannelParticipantCreator:
                                item = {
                                "Group Name": dialog.name,
                                "Name": user.first_name,
                                "Lastname": user.last_name,
                                "Telegram Address": "https://web.telegram.org/k/#"
                                + str(user.id),
                                "type" : "creator",
                                }
                            else:
                                item = {
                                "Group Name": dialog.name,
                                "Name": user.first_name,
                                "Lastname": user.last_name,
                                "Telegram Address": "https://web.telegram.org/k/#"
                                + str(user.id),
                                "type" : "admin",
                                    }
                            self.listed.append(item)
                            self.conversations[dialog.name].append(item)
```

This is the way how i am getting chat admins. But to reach that I need to join that group. Is there any way to get public group admins without joining?